# Convert binary string to text string

Tags: java, string

First, please do not mark as duplicate because I **know** the other SO post does not solve my issue..thank you.

I have a `String` variable called `M` which contains the binary value:

```
0001101 0010110 0011101 0001110 0010100 0010101 0010001 0001000 0000110 0000110 0001100 0001101 0011010 0011100 0010101 0001110 0011010 0011110 0001100 0000110 0011000 0001011 0001101 0000111 0011110 0001010 0001000 0010001 0000111 0011100 0001100 0001001 0010001 0001000 0010010 0001100 0001100 0011001 0010111 0001100 0010111 0000111 0001011 0010110 0010011 0011110 0010000 0010001 0010110 0010011 0011110 0001011 0010110 0000110 0001101 0011010 0011101 0001111 0000111 0000111 0011010 0011100 0001101 0011100 0011001 0011001 0011001 0011101 0011010 0010001 0010011 0010001 0011110 0010111 0001111 0001001 0010101 0011011 0001110 0001011 0011110 0011101 0000110 0011000 0000110 0010101 0001100 0001110 0010100 0011001 0011000 0001100 0001100 0001000 0011000 0001111 0001001 0011100 0011010 0011110 0010110 0011001 0011101 0001110 0010101 0011010 0000111 0010101 0010011 0000101 0010010 0001011 0011110 0001110 0011101 0010001 0001010 0011010 0010110 0011011 0011001 0011000 0010000 0010111 0001100 0010101 0001000 0000101 0000101 0011101 0001100 0010001 0011001 0001110 0001000 0001100 0010101 0001011 0001000 0010000 0001000 0001111 0010101 0001100 0001010 0001111 0011010 0010010 0010010 0011100 0011001 0011001 0010111 0001100 0010010 0000111 0000110 0011001 0001011 0011011 0001101 0011000 0011001 0010000 0000101 0000111 0010111 0000101 0011101 0000111 0010101 0011110 0001101 0011001 0001110 0011100 0001100 0011010 0010010 0011101 0000110 0001111 0011101 0010111 0010110 0011000 0010000 0001000 0001001 0011110 0010111 0001110 0000101 0001010 0001011 0001011 0011001 0011010 0010110 0010101 0001010 0001111 0001100 0011110 0001010 0010011 0011000 0000111 0010011 0001000 0010011 0011110 0011100 0001010 0011000 0011100 0011100 0010110 0011100 0010000 0011110 0001000 0011000 0000110 0001100 0001010 0011010 0011010 0000110 0010000 0001111 0010110 0001010 0010010 0010100 0011101 0011101 0011010 0001101 0011100 0001000 0011011 0010001 0010101 0010000 0010000 0010111 0001001 0011011 0011100 0001100 0010110 0001110 0001100 0011101 0011011
```

The appropriate text equivalent is:

```
ribqkjnwyysrecjqeasygtrxauwnxcsvnwmssfhshxtilaonilatiyrebpxxecrcfffbenlnahpvjdqtabygyjsqkfgsswgpvceaifbqjexjlzmtaqbnueidfgohsjwzzbsnfqwsjtwowpjsupemmcffhsmxyftdrgfozxhzbxjarfqcsembypbhigowvahqzuttfeijupsaulgxlwlacugccicoawgysueeyopiumkbbercwdnjoohvdcsiqsbd
```

I am trying to convert the `String` variable M from binary to text. Based upon what I understand, and read on other SO posts, I coded the following:

```
   int charCode = Integer.parseInt(M.trim(), 2);
   String str = new Character((char)charCode).toString();
```

where `M` is a `String` containing the binary value that I discussed above before, and `str` should be the appropriate text equivalent that you see above.

However, I am receiving the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0001101 0010110 0011101 0001110 0010100 0010101 0010001 0001000 0000110 0000110 0001100 0001101 0011010 0011100 0010101 0001110 0011010 0011110 0001100 0000110 0011000 0001011 0001101 0000111 0011110 0001010 0001000 0010001 0000111 0011100 0001100 0001001 0010001 0001000 0010010 0001100 0001100 0011001 0010111 0001100 0010111 0000111 0001011 0010110 0010011 0011110 0010000 0010001 0010110 0010011 0011110 0001011 0010110 0000110 0001101 0011010 0011101 0001111 0000111 0000111 0011010 0011100 0001101 0011100 0011001 0011001 0011001 0011101 0011010 0010001 0010011 0010001 0011110 0010111 0001111 0001001 0010101 0011011 0001110 0001011 0011110 0011101 0000110 0011000 0000110 0010101 0001100 0001110 0010100 0011001 0011000 0001100 0001100 0001000 0011000 0001111 0001001 0011100 0011010 0011110 0010110 0011001 0011101 0001110 0010101 0011010 0000111 0010101 0010011 0000101 0010010 0001011 0011110 0001110 0011101 0010001 0001010 0011010 0010110 0011011 0011001 0011000 0010000 0010111 0001100 0010101 0001000 0000101 0000101 0011101 0001100 0010001 0011001 0001110 0001000 0001100 0010101 0001011 0001000 0010000 0001000 0001111 0010101 0001100 0001010 0001111 0011010 0010010 0010010 0011100 0011001 0011001 0010111 0001100 0010010 0000111 0000110 0011001 0001011 0011011 0001101 0011000 0011001 0010000 0000101 0000111 0010111 0000101 0011101 0000111 0010101 0011110 0001101 0011001 0001110 0011100 0001100 0011010 0010010 0011101 0000110 0001111 0011101 0010111 0010110 0011000 0010000 0001000 0001001 0011110 0010111 0001110 0000101 0001010 0001011 0001011 0011001 0011010 0010110 0010101 0001010 0001111 0001100 0011110 0001010 0010011 0011000 0000111 0010011 0001000 0010011 0011110 0011100 0001010 0011000 0011100 0011100 0010110 0011100 0010000 0011110 0001000 0011000 0000110 0001100 0001010 0011010 0011010 0000110 0010000 0001111 0010110 0001010 0010010 0010100 0011101 0011101 0011010 0001101 0011100 0001000 0011011 0010001 0010101 0010000 0010000 0010111 0001001 0011011 0011100 0001100 0010110 0001110 0001100 0011101 0011011"
```

I researched this error, and then added the `trim` method thinking it would remove any trailing spaces, but that did not solve the error.

Is the `String` value too large? Any suggestions as to why and how to correct this issue are appreciated.

UPDATE:
Additionally details about error:

```
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at CaesarCipher.decrypt(C.java:194)
```

*Line 194 is:

```
   int charCode = Integer.parseInt(M.trim(), 2);
```

UPDATE #2: (I changed `result` to `result1`)
Given,

```
String result1 = "";
for(String binNum: M.trim().split(" ")){
     int charCode = Integer.parseInt(binNum, 2);
     result1+=Character.toString(charCode);
}
System.out.println(result1);
```

The error is:

```
error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to char
     result1+=Character.toString(charCode);
```

UPDATE #3:

Error corrected, but I am receiving the string:

```
mv}ntuqhfflmz|unz~lfxkmg~jhqg|liqhrllywlwgkvs~pqvs~kvfmz}oggz|m|yyy}zqsq~woiu{nk~}fxfulntyxllhxoi|z~vy}nuzguserk~n}qjzv{yxpwluhee}lqynhlukhphouljozrr|yywlrgfyk{mxypegwe}gu~myn|lzr}fo}wvxphi~wnejkkyzvujol~jsxgshs~|jx||v|p~hxfljzzfpovjrt}}zm|h{quppwi{|lvnl}{
```

when I should be receiving the string:

```
ribqkjnwyysrecjqeasygtrxauwnxcsvnwmssfhshxtilaonilatiyrebpxxecrcfffbenlnahpvjdqtabygyjsqkfgsswgpvceaifbqjexjlzmtaqbnueidfgohsjwzzbsnfqwsjtwowpjsupemmcffhsmxyftdrgfozxhzbxjarfqcsembypbhigowvahqzuttfeijupsaulgxlwlacugccicoawgysueeyopiumkbbercwdnjoohvdcsiqsbd
```

UPDATE #4:

When removing 96, I receive the following:

[image]
What is this?

Comment: Practically there is no limit for a String. Your String is so short to compared to what is used in the business. Please provide the details of your error.

Comment: Try split input string by spaces and process each piece.

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis Ok. Please see my update with all details provided about the error.

Comment: I think the spaces may be a problem. Further more it might be the value that is exceeding the limit of an Integer, so maybe try and parse it with `Long.parseLong(M, 2)`, and see if its still crashing. Otherwise youll need to split the String up in smaller bits (cause I havent checked it, but it might even exceed the limit of the Long value e.g. 64-bit)

Comment: The propblem is that the binary is **not** the string you think it is.

Comment: Re UPDATE #3: It looks like it is a cipher such as Vigenère cipher where the offset is not the same throughout but changes based on a key. Where did you get the binary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is it doesn't know what to do with the spaces between the binary numbers, and also that the whole string is not itself one number but a grouping of a bunch of numbers. The solution is to parse each individual number as a character and then collect the result.

You'll need to do something like this:

```
String result = "";
for(String binNum: M.trim().split(" ")){
     int charCode = Integer.parseInt(binNum, 2);
     result+=Character.toString((char)charCode);
}
System.out.println(result); // Here is the complete string...
```

Comment: Something like `96+charCode` if you look at the values.

Comment: Please see my update as I am receiving an error with this code. Thank you.

Comment: it has been updated, I've also added 96 as @Joop pointed out. If that doesn't work you should try removing 96.

Comment: I see...but the code does not correctly convert. Please see my update. I am sorry for my confusion.

Comment: @SamSmith like i said, try ```result+=Character.toString((char)charCode)```

Comment: I remove the 96, but I receive strange blocks. Please see my update. Perhaps you know what they are....

Comment: Ah, @SamSmith I was assuming this was just straight up ascii, but it seems like your binary is encrypted somehow. That is up to you to figure out since I don't know the context of your assignment. Just know that you'll have to transform the charCode for each character somehow.

Comment: Ohh...awesome. This is exactly what I was looking for then because the result of conversion is an encryption! To clarify, those blocks indicate an encryption? I have never seen them before.

Comment: No, those blocks indicate characters that aren't meant to be printed I.E. control characters or ones in the extended ascii space. See @zaph 's comment on alanin's answer.

Answer (score 0):

The numbers represent non-printable characters (those with values < 32).
As already pointed out, adding 96 can allow to get something printable.

Such conversion can be done as follows in Java 9:

```
new Scanner(M).tokens().map( n -> (char) (Integer.parseInt(n, 2) + 0x60) ).collect( StringBuilder::new, (a,b) -> a.append(b), (a,b) -> a.append(b) ).toString()
```

or in case you are still using Java 8:

```
Arrays.stream( M.split(" ") ).map( n -> (char) (Integer.parseInt(n, 2) + 0x60) ).collect( StringBuilder::new, (a,b) -> a.append(b), (a,b) -> a.append(b) ).toString()
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not entirely sure. But looks right to me.

What youre doing is printing each binary code letter in one line

Like the letter value of 0001101 = r, 0010110 = i, 0011101 = b, etc.

those numbers are the first 3 binary values and the letters your first 3 string values

Comment: 00001101 is not 'r', it is carrage return. 0010110 is not  i, it is file separator Escape. 0011101 is not b, it is group seperator.

Comment: Does that mean that string value r = carrage return?

And i would love to know what 0000110 is. I wouldnt be suprised if it is not "y"

Comment: @alanin not it means the ascii character with value 0b00001101 is the carriage return.

Comment: See [ASCII Table and Description](http://www.asciitable.com). 0000110 is 0x06 which is `acknowledge`. Most of the ASCII codes 0x00 thru 0x1f were control codes for controlling teleprinters, modems and other hardware.